# How to insert multiple Json data to hbase using NiFI.?

Tags: json, hbase, apache-nifi

Please tell me how to insert multiple json data into hbase using Nifi

[PutHbaseJson Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQTUL.png)

[PutHbaseCell Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31jJI.png)
when we try to insert more than one id's or object.
This is the file which i have tried with PutHbaseCell

```
{"id" : "1334134","name" : "Apparel Fabric","path" : "Arts, Crafts & Sewing/Fabric/Apparel Fabric"},
{"id" : "412","name" : "Apparel Fabric","path" : "Arts, Crafts & Sewing/Fabric/Apparel Fabric"}
```

[Image of PutHbaseCell Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmJV5.jpg)

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: i have tried puthbasejson processor but it store as like

Comment: file.json

[
"category":{
     {"id":1,"name":"abc","path":"c:/ddd"},
{"id":2,"name":"abcd","path":"d:/ccc"}
                 }
]


i have tried puthbasejson processor but it store as like
ROW     COLUMN
1       column=details:name, value=abc
1       column=details:path, value=c:/ddd
2       column=details:name, value=abcd
2       column=details:path, value=d:/ccc

Comment: I have also tried putHbaseCell but it store as like this
ROW               COLUMN
1          column=details:category, value={"id":1,"name"="abc"},{"id":2,"name"="abcdef"}

All objects which is in one array are stored in one row

Comment: @Umangsoni, add your sample data and its result in your question

Answer (score 0):

PutHBaseJson expects each flow file to contain one JSON document which becomes a row in HBase. The row id can be specified in the processor using expression language, or it can come from one of the fields in the JSON. The other field/value pairs in the JSON become the the columns/values of the row in HBase.

If you want to use PutHBaseJson, you just need to split up your data in NiFi before it reaches this processor. There are many ways to do this.. SplitJson, SplitText, SplitContent, ExecuteScript, a custom processors.

Alternatively there is a PutHBaseRecord processors which can use a record reader to read records from a flow file and send them all to HBase. In your case you would need a JSON record reader. The data also has to be in a format that is understood by the record reader, and I believe for JSON it would need to be an array of documents.